# nodenv にて、 rbenv における .ruby-version 相当のものはありますか

Tags: node.js, nodenv

ruby の rbenv には、対象リポジトリをどの ruby を用いて実行するかを指定する `.ruby-version` があります。 nodejs の nodenv にも同様のものがあるのではないかと思いました。

#### 質問

- nodenv に、リポジトリ(ディレクトリ)の隠しファイルで、そこにバージョンを記述しておくと、 nodenv がよろしくそのバージョンでもって実行してくれるようなファイルのしくみは存在しますか?

Comment: [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) ではなく [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) ですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 普段 ruby では rvm よりも rbenv を使っているので、 nodejs についても nodenv を使おうかと思ったので、 nodenv です。 実運用上もはや使われない構成である、とかであれば nvm を使うことも検討しようかとは思います。

Comment: nodenvは使ってませんが、ndenvを使ってます。(anyenv経由でインストール)  ndenvには、 .node-versionファイルがあり rbenvと同様にバージョンを指定できます。便利です。

Comment: @tanalab2 なるほど、、 ndenv というものもあるんですね…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

はい、nodenv にも `.node-version` というローカル用設定ファイルが存在します。

以下、nodenv の [README.md](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv/blob/18489d7bf319fde4edc942cce7f3b1caf1b12214/README.md) の "Coosing the Node Version" からの引用です。

> 2. The first `.node-version` file found by searching the directory of the script you are executing and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem.
> 3. The first `.node-version` file found by searching the current working directory and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem. You can modify the `.node-version` file in the current working directory with the [`nodenv local`](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv/blob/18489d7bf319fde4edc942cce7f3b1caf1b12214/README.md#nodenv-local) command.

和訳:

> 2. スクリプトを実行したディレクトリから、ファイルシステムのルートに達するまで親ディレクトリを探索していき、最初に見つかった `.node-version` ファイル
> 3. 現在作業中のディレクトリから、ファイルシステムのルートに達するまで親ディレクトリを探索していき、最初に見つかった `.node-version` ファイル。この `.node-version` ファイルは、作業中のディレクトリで [`nodenv local`](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv/blob/18489d7bf319fde4edc942cce7f3b1caf1b12214/README.md#nodenv-local) コマンドを使うことで変更できます。